# cant figure out SQL syntax for this code

Tags: mysql

Its between so long since i did SQL when i try to paste this code into phpmyadmin database it wont create the table i get error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, WORKER CHAR(30), CONSTRAINT WORKER_FK FOREIGN KEY(WORKE' at line 2
```

this is code for the sql table:

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT(
 REPORT_ID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  WORKER CHAR(30) CONSTRAINT WORKER_FK FOREIGN KEY(WORKER) REFERENCES WORKER(WORKER_ID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CLIENT CHAR (30) CONSTRAINT CLIENT_FK FOREIGN KEY(client) REFERENCES CLIENT(CLIENT_ID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
 START_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT STARTDATE_FK FOREIGN KEY(JOB) REFERENCES JOB(START_DATE)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  END_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT ENDDATE_FK FOREIGN KEY(JOB) REFERENCES JOB(END_DATE)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  COMMENT CHAR(30)
 )engine innoDB;
```

can anyone help me out please

Comment: Do the CLIENT, WORKER, and JOB tables exist? do they have the referenced columns?

Comment: yea the tables do exisits. i will have look again see did i just mess up with names or something some where. THanks

Comment: thanks a_horse_with_no_name i was just confused thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual error message comes from the fact that report_id doesn't have a data type.

```
REPORT_ID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

should be

```
REPORT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
```

But you have a lot more problems. The "inline" foreign keys are silently ignored by MySQL - even with InnoDB. You have to move them to the end.

Additionally your foreign key to the jobs table can not be correct. First off, there is no `job` column in your table, so `FOREIGN KEY(JOB) REFERENCES JOB(END_DATE)` can't be correct.

Secondly you are referencing two different PK definitions to the same table. My guess is you actually want:

```
CONSTRAINT START_END_DATE_FK 
   FOREIGN KEY (START_DATE, END_DATE) 
   REFERENCES JOB(START_DATE, END_DATE)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET NULL,
```

This assumes that `(START_DATE, END_DATE)` is the primary key of the `JOB` table - which does sound a bit strange.

Not sure if `comment` is a reserved word in MySQL. If it is, you need to quote the column name.

So put this alltogether, you probably need something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT
(
  REPORT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  WORKER CHAR(30) ,
  CLIENT CHAR (30),
  START_DATE DATE ,
  END_DATE DATE,
  COMMENT CHAR(30),
  CONSTRAINT WORKER_FK FOREIGN KEY(WORKER) REFERENCES WORKER(WORKER_ID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT CLIENT_FK FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES CLIENT(CLIENT_ID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT START_END_DATE_FK FOREIGN KEY (START_DATE, END_DATE) REFERENCES JOB(START_DATE, END_DATE)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ENDDATE_FK FOREIGN KEY(JOB) REFERENCES JOB(END_DATE)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining a column type for `REPORT_ID`. ie `REPORT_ID int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,`

```
CREATE TABLE REPORT(
 REPORT_ID int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  WORKER CHAR(30) CONSTRAINT WORKER_FK FOREIGN KEY(WORKER) REFERENCES WORKER(WORKER_ID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CLIENT CHAR (30) CONSTRAINT CLIENT_FK FOREIGN KEY(client) REFERENCES CLIENT(CLIENT_ID)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
 START_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT STARTDATE_FK FOREIGN KEY(JOB) REFERENCES JOB(START_DATE)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  END_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT ENDDATE_FK FOREIGN KEY(JOB) REFERENCES JOB(END_DATE)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE SET NULL,
  COMMENT CHAR(30)
 )engine innoDB;
```

Comment: `int(11)` is useless (`int` is exactly the same thing). And the foreign keys defined this way *will* be ignored.

Comment: thanks everyone for clearing up my confusing and helping out :)